# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: php, amfphp

First of all, am not a Php geek.. so excuse my little knowledge around PHP stuff.
I am using AMFPHP2 with Flex on frontend.
I can pull data from backend as typed objects fine, but when I try to save, i am having this issue as below:

```
<br /><b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in <b>/mnt/array1/share/htdocs/htdocs/admin/application/amf/services/Item.php</b> on line <b>88</b><br />
```

Below is the code throwing this error:

```
Line86    public function saveCollection($collection) {
Line87        for ($i=0; $i<count($collection); $i++) {
Line88            $this->saveItem($collection[$i]);
Line89        }
Line90    }
```

Below are my VO classes:
ItemVO.php

```
class ItemVO {
..
..
var $_explicitType = "ItemVO";
..
..
}
```

ItemVO.as

```
package models.vo {
    [RemoteClass(alias="ItemVO")]  
    public class ItemVO {
...
...
    }
}
```

Here is my folder structure:

```
-root/
------*.html
------*.swf
------application/
-----------------amf/
--------------------/index.php
--------------------/models/vo/all vo files
--------------------/services/all services
-----------------libraries/
--------------------------/Amfphp/
```

Here is my index.php

```
<?php
require_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/libraries/Amfphp/ClassLoader.php';
$config = new Amfphp_Core_Config();
$config->serviceFolderPaths = array(dirname(__FILE__) . '/services/');
$voFolders = array(dirname(__FILE__) . '/models/vo/');
$customClassConverterConfig = array(‘customClassFolderPaths’ => $voFolders);
$config->pluginsConfig['AmfphpCustomClassConverter'] = $customClassConverterConfig;
$gateway = Amfphp_Core_HttpRequestGatewayFactory::createGateway($config);
$gateway->service();
$gateway->output();
?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: you can try var_dump($collection) on line 87.it may give a hint on the problem.

Comment: A better solution than just dumping the entire variable, especially if it's very large, would be gettype($collection);

Comment: Looks like on PHP side we can't handle ArrayCollections. I tried my code by sending Arrays from clientside instead of ArrayCollections, and it worked as it is. Many thanks for all the inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error-message is self-explaining.
You may use e.g. this:

```
public function saveCollection($collection) {
 foreach ($collection as $value) {
          $this->saveItem($value);
       }
   }
```

Comment: I had already tried that. Error still remains with "$this->saveItem($value);" line

Comment: The same error or a different error? What does $collection contain?

Comment: saveCollection(updateItems) is being called as _remote.saveCollection(updateItems) from client side Flex code. Where _remote is a RemoteObject on client side and updateItems is an ArrayCollection of Typed objects. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

My basic understanding of the error is that you are trying to access an object as if it was an array.

That usually means that you are doing `$something['something']` instead of the correct `$something->something`.

Is the `$collection` parameter in `saveCollection`an array or an object?

Try replacing Line 88 with:

```
 $this->saveItem($collection->$i);
```

**Edit -**

As I just realized in the comments, it shouldn't work anyway because you are trying to count an `stdClass`. Using `for each`should do the trick, as someone else mentioned in an answer.

Comment: I don't think you can call `count` with an object...can you?

Comment: @Travesty3 `stdClass` doesn't implement the `Countable` interface, so no. `count` should always return 1 in those cases. If it's structure is pretty simple, you can cast it to an array like: `count((array)$stdObj)`

Comment: I was just pointing out that you didn't address that part of the OP's code in your solution. You suggested the only thing he needs to change is the code _inside_ the for-loop, but he will also need to change the end condition of the for-loop itself. Might want to modify your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing a `stdClass` *object* like an *array*, the two are not the same thing. For your purpose, you may be able to cast it as an array:

```
public function saveCollection($collection) {
    $collection = (array)$collection;
    for ($i=0; $i<count($collection); $i++) {
        $this->saveItem($collection[$i]);
    }
}
```

NOTE: Casting an object as an array doesn't always work, but since it looks like you are expecting an array-like structure to be passed in, it will probably work fine.